# Errors building DLL with matplotplusplus dependency

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

In my first ever Visual Studio C++ DLL template project I'm attempting to `#include <matplot/matplot.h>` but I'm receiving a lot of errors on build caused by this include. The errors are pasted at the end of this question.

I've installed the library using `vcpkg install matplotplusplus:x64-windows` and run the integrate command.

In a console app project the errors don't appear and I can interact with the library successfully. However within the DLL project it will not build. Is there some special project configuration I may be missing? Is this library just not able to be used in a DLL, and if so what alternate library should I consider?

My ultimate goal is to provide a DLL which can be used in other applications to generate non-interactive plots as .svg, I'm not looking to use the interactive plotting features of the library.

```
1>C:\Users\my_user\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\matplot\util\common.h(101,12): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'min'
1>C:\Users\my_user\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\matplot\util\common.h(101,12): error C2059: syntax error: 'const'
1>C:\Users\my_user\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\matplot\util\common.h(101,12): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
1>C:\Users\my_user\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\matplot\util\common.h(102,12): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'min'
1>C:\Users\my_user\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\matplot\util\common.h(102,12): error C2059: syntax error: 'const'
1>C:\Users\my_user\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\matplot\util\common.h(102,12): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
1>C:\Users\my_user\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\matplot\util\common.h(103,12): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'max'
1>C:\Users\my_user\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\matplot\util\common.h(103,12): error C2059: syntax error: 'const'
1>C:\Users\my_user\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\matplot\util\common.h(103,12): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
1>C:\Users\my_user\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\matplot\util\common.h(104,12): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'max'
1>C:\Users\my_user\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\matplot\util\common.h(104,12): error C2059: syntax error: 'const'
1>C:\Users\my_user\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\matplot\util\common.h(104,12): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
1>C:\Users\my_user\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\matplot\util\common.h(107,29): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'val1'
1>C:\Users\my_user\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\matplot\util\common.h(107,29): error C2365: 'T': redefinition; previous definition was 'template parameter'
1>C:\Users\my_user\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\matplot\util\common.h(107,27): message : see declaration of 'T'
1>C:\Users\my_user\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\matplot\util\common.h(107,29): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'val1'
1>C:\Users\my_user\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\matplot\util\common.h(107): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
1>C:\Users\my_user\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\matplot\util\common.h(107,29): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'val2'
1>C:\Users\my_user\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\matplot\util\common.h(107,29): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'val2'
1>C:\Users\my_user\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\matplot\util\common.h(107,49): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
1>C:\Users\my_user\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\matplot\util\common.h(107,49): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>C:\Users\my_user\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\matplot\util\common.h(111,45): warning C4002: too many arguments for function-like macro invocation 'min'
1>C:\Users\my_user\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\matplot\util\common.h(111,45): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'val1'
1>C:\Users\my_user\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\matplot\util\common.h(111,45): error C2365: 'T': redefinition; previous definition was 'template parameter'
1>C:\Users\my_user\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\matplot\util\common.h(111,43): message : see declaration of 'T'
1>C:\Users\my_user\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\matplot\util\common.h(111,45): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'val1'
1>C:\Users\my_user\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\matplot\util\common.h(111): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
1>C:\Users\my_user\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\matplot\util\common.h(111,45): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'val2'
1>C:\Users\my_user\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\matplot\util\common.h(111,45): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'val2'
1>C:\Users\my_user\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\matplot\util\common.h(111,78): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
1>C:\Users\my_user\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\matplot\util\common.h(111,78): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>C:\Users\my_user\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\matplot\util\common.h(116,29): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'val1'
1>C:\Users\my_user\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\matplot\util\common.h(116,29): error C2365: 'T': redefinition; previous definition was 'template parameter'
1>C:\Users\my_user\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\matplot\util\common.h(116,27): message : see declaration of 'T'
1>C:\Users\my_user\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\matplot\util\common.h(116,29): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'val1'
1>C:\Users\my_user\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\matplot\util\common.h(116): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
1>C:\Users\my_user\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\matplot\util\common.h(116,29): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'val2'
1>C:\Users\my_user\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\matplot\util\common.h(116,29): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'val2'
1>C:\Users\my_user\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\matplot\util\common.h(116,49): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
1>C:\Users\my_user\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\matplot\util\common.h(116,49): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>C:\Users\my_user\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\matplot\util\common.h(120,45): warning C4002: too many arguments for function-like macro invocation 'max'
1>C:\Users\my_user\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\matplot\util\common.h(120,45): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'val1'
1>C:\Users\my_user\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\matplot\util\common.h(120,45): error C2365: 'T': redefinition; previous definition was 'template parameter'
1>C:\Users\my_user\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\matplot\util\common.h(120,43): message : see declaration of 'T'
1>C:\Users\my_user\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\matplot\util\common.h(120,45): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'val1'
1>C:\Users\my_user\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\matplot\util\common.h(120): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
1>C:\Users\my_user\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\matplot\util\common.h(120,45): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'val2'
1>C:\Users\my_user\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\matplot\util\common.h(120,45): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'val2'
1>C:\Users\my_user\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\matplot\util\common.h(120,78): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
1>C:\Users\my_user\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\matplot\util\common.h(120,78): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>C:\Users\my_user\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\matplot\util\common.h(450,47): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'max'
1>C:\Users\my_user\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\matplot\util\common.h(450,47): error C2589: '(': illegal token on right side of '::'
1>C:\Users\my_user\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\matplot\util\common.h(450,47): error C2760: syntax error: ')' was unexpected here; expected 'expression'
1>C:\Users\my_user\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\matplot\util\common.h(450,47): error C2760: syntax error: ')' was unexpected here; expected ';'
1>C:\Users\my_user\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\matplot\util\common.h(450,47): error C3878: syntax error: unexpected token ')' following 'expression_statement'
1>C:\Users\my_user\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\matplot\util\common.h(450,47): message : error recovery skipped: ') >'
1>C:\Users\my_user\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\matplot\util\common.h(450,47): message : error recovery skipped: ') ) ?'
1>C:\Users\my_user\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\matplot\util\common.h(450,47): message : error recovery skipped: ') :'
1>C:\Users\my_user\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\matplot\util\common.h(450,47): message : error recovery skipped: ') )'
```

Comment: I think you need to define NOMINMAX before including `windows.h` if you are using that. If you are not using it remove it.

Comment: @drescherjm I'm not using `windows.h`

Comment: @drescherjm however defining NOMINMAX does remove the errors

Comment: *I'm not using windows.h* -- You may not be, but some file is using it.  The `min` and `max` macro fiasco is what happens when `windows.h` is included *somewhere*.  Those macros clash with `std::min` and `std::max` from `<algorithm>`.

Comment: BTW. for your own code that uses the `<algorithm>` version of `min` and `max`, if you get those `min` and `max` errors, another way to get rid of them is to use the alternate function calling syntax.  Something like `x = (std::min)(arg1, arg2);` -- in other words surround the function name with parentheses.  That works regardless of whether `NOMINMAX` is used.  This has always been a problem with `windows.h` -- code that compiles perfectly all-of-a-sudden breaks because of those macros.  Sometimes it's easier to use `NOMINMAX`, other times easier to just change to the parenthesized names.

Comment: https://github.com/alandefreitas/matplotplusplus/blob/2a8eada7d508a5ed158598888d38a54fe311c934/CMakeLists.txt#L81